# How to escape characters in Pango markup?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pango

My program has a `gtk.TreeView` which displays a `gtk.ListStore`. The `gtk.ListStore` contains strings like this:

```
"<span size='medium'><b>"+site_title+"</b></span>"+"\n"+URL
```

Where `URL` is (obviously) a URL string. Sometimes there are characters in `URL` that cause pango to fail to parse the markup.

Is there a way to escape `URL` as a whole so that pango will just ignore it so it will be displayed literally? If not, how should I "escape" special characters in URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the values.  I'm not sure what exact format Pango requires, but it looks like HTML and the [cgi.escape](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) function may be all you need.

```
import cgi
print "<span size='medium'><b>%s</b></span>\n%s" %
      (cgi.escape(site_title), cgi.escape(URL))
```

Answer (score 22):

[`glib.markup_escape_text`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/glib-functions.html#function-glib--markup-escape-text) may be a more canonical approach when using GTK.

Comment: In the latest version of PyGTK it appears to be [gobject.markup_escape_text](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--markup-escape-text)

Comment: The link in the answer is broken; docs appear to be here: https://docs.gtk.org/glib/func.markup_escape_text.html

Answer (score 0):

//edit queue is full, so post here

`GLib.markup_escape_text` from `PyGObject`

### demo

```py
>>> from gi.repository import GLib
>>> GLib.markup_escape_text('abc \b \f < & >')
'abc &#x8; &#xc; &lt; &amp; &gt;'
>>>
```

py api docs
https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GLib-2.0/functions.html#GLib.markup_escape_text
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io

c api docs
https://docs.gtk.org/glib/func.markup_escape_text.html